# The terminal editor on the NG alias

Tags: angular, windows

i bought a new windows computer and I tried to install Angular, but the ng commands are not working or opens a file in the editor instead.

I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980708/ng-serve-opens-editor-instead-of-loading-local-url) that `sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin` should fix the problem, but when I try to run the command in powershell, it says that apt is not recognized.
Then i tried apt-get instead, but nothing changed.

Then I installed chocolately and tried to run `choco purge ng-common ng-latin`, but now it says "Could not find a command registered that meets 'purge'."

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `sudo` and `apt` and `apt-get` are not Windows commands. They work on Linux. There is no `purge` command for Chocolatey CLI (i.e. `choco`). That is why none of those worked. My suggestion would be to go back to the Angular docs and understand how to install and use it on _Windows_.

Comment: @pauby thank you, I followed the doc but still its not working, when i try to run ng serve it opens ng.js and a serve file in the editor. 
I never had this problem on mac so im really confused

Answer (score 1):

`ng` is a node binary. This means you need NodeJS to make it work.

When you install NodeJS, you also install NPM, its package manager.

Once you have NPM, you can run `npm i -g @angular/cli@latest` to get the binary, and after that, you can use it.

Altough I answered you, as the comment said, you should really understand how the basics work before starting angular. Not even knowing the difference between windows and Linux is a huge issue, and not even reading the documentation about installing angular is an even bigger red flag.

Comment: Hello @MGX, thank you but I already have NodeJS and NPM installed, as well as Angular. The problem is that when I try to run ng serve on my old angular project, it opens the editor instead, and opens ng.js file and 'serve' file.
Same if I try to use ng new project, it opens an ng.js file, a 'new' file, and a 'project' file instead of creating a new project.

I worked on angular for the past 3 years on mac and i never had this kind of problem

Comment: Then I would suggest you install and use WSL : this is a Linux OS embedded inside windows. Installation is very straightforward, and you'll get all the perks of having Linux, combined with windows !